Getting different prices for a token when trying to swap on Uniswap, wallet, others
when the pop up for the swap comes up, it shows the token you are swapping to with a price directly under it. But on the sites page, if you scroll down to the bottom right, you will see where you can enter your amount of tokens and a price in either USD or WETH. That value and the one in the pop up are drastically different. The pop up shows half the value of the page itself. Why is that? seems pretty scammmy to me. Makes me want to stay away from Uniswap. Below I have circled what I am talking about.

This is common behaviour with scam tokens.

This is common behaviour with scam tokens.
Likely the token has

Very low liquidity
Some sort of a scam feature like token tax built-in

